# Can't generate RSA public key

Tags: java, rsa, public-key-encryption, stringtokenizer

I'm trying to learn about rsa public key generations. After some researches I create an "simple" code that should return a public key but I don't know why, it doesn't. Can anyone tell me why and explaine it?

```
public static byte[] GetTokens(String paramString) {
    StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(paramString, ",");
    byte[] arrayOfByte = new byte[stringTokenizer.countTokens()];
    for (byte b1 = 0; stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens(); b1++) {
       arrayOfByte[b1] = Byte.parseByte(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
    }
    return arrayOfByte;
}

public static PublicKey GenPublicKey() throws Exception {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader  = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input_text"));

    try {
        String str1 = bufferedReader.readLine();
        String str2 = bufferedReader.readLine();
        
        BigInteger bigInteger1 = new BigInteger(GetTokens(str1));
        BigInteger bigInteger2 = new BigInteger(GetTokens(str2));
        
        RSAPublicKeySpec rSAPublicKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(bigInteger1, bigInteger2);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(rSAPublicKeySpec);
        return publicKey;
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception thrown : " + e);
        throw new IOException("Error reading key, ");
    }

    finally {
        try {
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (Exception exception) {}
    }
}
```

To testing it I wrote aleatory numbers on "input_text" file:
8,33
6,18

Comment: The modulus has to be the multiplication of two primes. `8` is `2*2*2` hence not a valid modulus. One error in your code: use `BigInteger(1, GetTokens(...))`

Comment: Although generated _using_ randomness (entropy), RSA keys do _not_ consist of random bytes. In particular the two bytes 8,33 represent the number 2081 which is not a valid RSA modulus because it is not the product of distinct primes, and the two bytes 6,18 represent 1554 which is not a valid RSA public exponent because it is not coprime to _any_ Carmichael totient. Also modern crypto data including RSA keys is usually not represented textually (JWK is an exception, but not directly supported in Java), and almost never as separate bytes, especially in Java where `byte` is _signed_.

Comment: @Robert: RSA doesn't strictly have to be _two_ primes, although that was the original paper, and still the overwhelmingly most common use. It _can_ be any set of distinct primes all of which are large enough and unguessable (usually implemented as randomly chosen); if the modulus was 8, which it isn't in the example, then yes 2x2x2 are neither distinct nor large enough.

Comment: Considering that the GetTokens method uses the stringTokenizer which in turn has a range of -128:127, could I somehow define "random" numbers in the input_text to generate the publickey? @dave_thompson_085

Comment: Actually `Byte.parseByte` has the range -128:127, not `StringTokenizer`. But more importantly, as I said, you cannot generate a valid RSA key by choosing the bytes of its representation. You initially generate a keypair as _large numbers meeting the required conditions_ -- typically as in AhmedSHA256's answer, although you _can_ do this part 'by hand' -- and then if you want a byte-oriented representation create it _from_ the numbers. In practice no one uses bytes in decimal (even unsigned much less signed), although it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I will provide the code you need to generate a RSA public key:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        // We generate an instance that allows to create private/public key pairs
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");

        // We use 1024 bits lenght
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);

        // We generate key pair
        KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();

        // Original message
        String originalMessage = "Hello";

        // We obtain public key
        Key publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();

        // We convert the string in order to send the Key to the emitter
        String publicKeyText = keyToString(publicKey);
        System.out.println("Public key: " + publicKeyText);
    }

    private static String keyToString(Key publicKey) {
        byte[] publicKeyBytes = publicKey.getEncoded();
        String key = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(publicKeyBytes);

        return key;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't configure the KeyPairGenerator to create 1024 bit RSA key. Such keys are considered insecure. RSA keys should have a minimum of 2048 bit today.

Comment: Then make it 4096

Comment: The purpose of my comment was that you edit your answer and update it with an appropriate value. Please do not post insecure code.

Comment: @Robert this is one of my notes when I was learning Java like 4 years ago, so I didnt know it was outdated. Thanks for everything